# Exclude categories by ID

Tags: categories, terms, exclude

I've searched this site and tried all kinds of ways to exclude categories 1 and 7 from this list, but nothing is working. No errors but doesn't hide the cats either.

Categories 1 and 7 are not empty, but I'd also like to exclude empty categories, so !empty must stay.

```
<!-- category list with thumbs -->
<?php
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'category') );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

  foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
      echo '<div class="issue clear"><h3><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>';
      echo '<div class="grid col-120 hide"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '"><img src="IMG SRC" alt="" /></a></div>';
      echo '<div class="grid col-780 fit">'. $term->description . '</div></div>';
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: Is this a plugin? You may need to contact them, I'm not sure how their filter works. That being said, the non-ideal way would be to add an `if` statement in your `foreach` `if($term->term_id != 7 || $term->term_id != 8)` - alternatively you could put the ids in an array and use something like `!in_array()`

Comment: Yes, it's a plugin: Taxonomy Images. Thanks, I've tried excluding term IDs like that, and in a zillion other ways. Feel like pulling my hair at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You could try modifying your query such that you have an array of categories to exclude and a conditional in the `foreach`, working similarly to the `!empty()`. An untested example:

```
<!-- category list with thumbs -->
<?php
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'category') );
$exclude = array(1,7); //add the category IDs to exlcude here

if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

  foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {

        //check the category's ID and output code
        //if it's not in the $exclude array
        if ( ! in_array($term->term_id, $exclude) ) {
            echo '<div class="issue clear"><h3><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></h3>';
            echo '<div class="grid col-120 hide"><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '"><img src="IMG SRC" alt="" /></a></div>';
            echo '<div class="grid col-780 fit">'. $term->description . '</div></div>';
        }//if in_array

    }//for each

}//if empty
?>
```

Comment: i've tried this, it didn't work for whatever reason. I should've mentioned that I was working with a Multisite setup, and the plugin is only compatible up to WP 3.6. I removed the plugin and rewrote the function completely, relying only on WP basics and Advanced Custom Fields. --  Thanks for giving it a shot.